# Suddenly, Google Chrome Always Asks for Administrator Privileges

Tags: google-chrome

Suddenly, Google Chrome Always Asks for Administrator Privileges since this morning.
It didn't to that.

I use 6.0.472.63 version on Win7 64bit.

It is very annoying me. I uninstalled and reinstalled but it still asks it.
Why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening the properties of the program and click on the compatiblity tab and see if "run as administrator" is checked.  If so the uncheck it and this should resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I haven't ever touched it. Who changes it. Is it a virus? I uninstalled it and install Chrome 7 Beta. It works well now. Very weird. Thanks anyway.